# When my Petition will be in processing State in USCIS for Form I-130, my case approved in may 2015?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, us-citizens, greencard

I've applied for US Immigration on base of my parents and form is **Form I-130, Immigrant Petition for Relative, Fiance(E), or Orphan.** and Form Type is **Permanent resident filling for an unmarried son or daughter over 21** I applied on start of 2015 and Approved on **June 2015**. I also saw on this [website](https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/#mainContent) current processing date which is **case inquiry date** in this website as shown in picture [image]. So I want to know following question

- When I'll get final confirmation and start process for my Visa to US
- What is the speed of **case Inquiry date**, as for my case its around 10months behind current **October 16, 2014** but I don't know how long this will take to come to **June 2015**

Answer (score 4):

The processing times is no longer relevant because you said your I-130 has already been approved. The processing times are for how long the particular application (in your case I-130) takes to approve, but yours has already been approved.

You need to wait until a visa number becomes available for your priority date and category before you can proceed to the next step. The I-130 being approved by itself does not allow you to do anything. Which priority dates (for family-based immigration, the priority date is the date the I-130 was filed) have a visa number available is published each month in the [visa bulletin](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin.html). An unmarried over-21 child of a permanent resident is in the F2B category, and currently visa numbers are only available in that category for priority dates in Apr 2011 for people born in most countries (in 1996 and 2006 for people born in Mexico and the Philippines, respectively). You can use this to estimate how long it will take before a visa number will become available. If the wait remains the same, and you weren't born in Mexico or the Philippines, you can expect a visa number to become available for your priority date around 2022.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm an Indian. 
can you tell me difference between
FINAL ACTION DATES FOR FAMILY-SPONSORED PREFERENCE CASES
And 
DATES FOR FILING FAMILY-SPONSORED VISA APPLICATIONS

Comment: @Aleem Where do you see those options?

Comment: @mkennedy: the visa bulletin for each month

Comment: @Aleem: If you are doing Consular Processing abroad, the consulate will start processing your case around when the Date for Filing passes your priority date, but they cannot finally issue you the immigrant visa until a month when the Final Action Date is past your priority date.

Comment: @user102008 I've just seen Visa Bulletin, it mentioned that in the last process of Final Action Date For Family Sponsor reference date is 01JUN14 for India Column, so should I consider that only 1 year is left as already explained my case on above. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin/2020/visa-bulletin-for-october-2019.html

Comment: The last year on April last action date mention on Visa Bulletin was on April 2011 but from past 1.5years it covered around 3.5years cases as it moved to 01JUN14, so should I expect it'll open within year as it is now on 01JUN14 and my case is approve on May 2015 ?

Comment: 01JUN14 showing in India column and I'm from Pakistan so I think I'll fall into same column

Comment: @Aleem: Were you born in India or Pakistan? It's the place of birth that matters. If you were born in Pakistan, you would not fall in the India column; you would fall in the All Chargeability Areas Except Those Listed column. But F2B is currently the same for India as All Chargeability Areas Except Those Listed. Your priority date is the date the I-130 was filed (you said "start of 2015"?), not when it was approved. Your receipt should list the priority date.

Comment: alright, Yes I'm from Pakistan
but my question is still there that according to last year processing speed it looks like that 1 year is left if processing goes at this pace, as filled status is on  01DEC14 for DATES FOR FILING FAMILY-SPONSORED VISA APPLICATIONS. 
My process is filled on March 2015 and approved on May 2015.
So am I assuming right ?

Comment: @user102008 If not then what is right and roughly how many time is required according to my information?

Comment: @Aleem: So when the date on the chart becomes later than March 2015, you can expect the process to start. I can't predict how the chart moves, but your expectation of 1 year left is reasonable.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks for your answer. If you've idea, I've one more query lets say the date on the chart becomes later than March 2015 so what will be next process ?

Comment: @Aleem: If you are doing Consular Processing abroad, you will be contacted by NVC

Comment: Thanks @user102008